# Create materialized views from Google Cloud PostgreSQL in BigQuery

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, materialized-views

We have a database in **Google Cloud SQL** which has partitioned tables created with same naming format every month.
I would like to create and update materialized view from these partitioned tables for last few days (updated every 5-10 mins), last few weeks or months (updated every hour or daily).

Is using **BigQuery** right way of doing so? I couldn't find a way to pull data in some of the ingestion guides.

If I do it in PostgreSQL instance itself, what is the best way to update (I have created `materialized view` in the past but didn't update them)?

Comment: Do you want to have a BigQUery materialized view with PostgreSQL source?

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to go with materialized view on cloud postgres itself and added a cloud function to update the mview midnight using cloud trigger.